# ¿Es posible usar comodines para buscar en contenido con Windows Search?

Tags: sql, .net, windows, busqueda

Estoy utilizando el servicio de indización de Windows Search, para localizar contenido dentro de documentos.
He notado que si un documento tiene una palabra como camión y pongo que busque cam, no encuentra coincidencias, mientras que si pongo la palabra completa sí devuelve resultados.

Mi pregunta es, si es posible utilizar caracteres comodín en esas búsquedas.
Sé que para el nombre del fichero es posible, pero me interesa para el contenido.

Ejemplo de sentencias usadas:

```
SQL = "SELECT System.ItemPathDisplay, System.Search.Rank " &
      " FROM SystemIndex " &
      " WHERE scope ='" & SEARCH_DIRECTORY & "' AND FREETEXT('" & sSearchString & "') " &
      " ORDER BY System.Search.Rank DESC "
```

```
SQL = "SELECT System.ItemPathDisplay, System.Search.Rank " &
      " FROM SystemIndex " &
      " WHERE scope ='" & SEARCH_DIRECTORY & "' AND CONTAINS('" & sSearchString & "') " &
      " ORDER BY System.Search.Rank DESC "
```

He estado probando a añadir caracteres comodín en esas sentencias freetext y contains pero no sirven, y tampoco encuentro ejemplos por internet.

En este caso se puede, pero no me interesa el nombre:

```
WHERE scope ='{sFolder}' AND System.ItemName LIKE '%{" & sSearchString & "}%'
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final encontré solución a usar comodines. **Contains** sí que los soporta, pero hay que poner unas comillas extra:

```
SQL = "SELECT System.ItemPathDisplay, System.Search.Rank " &
      " FROM SystemIndex " &
      " WHERE scope ='" & SEARCH_DIRECTORY & "' AND CONTAINS('""" & sSearchString & " ""')" &
      " ORDER BY System.Search.Rank DESC "
```